# Compile time error due to invalid method usage

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am trying to create a custom URL shortener using YOURLS. When I use the built in API in YOURLS, this is what comes up in chrome as an XML document:

```
<result>
<url>
<keyword>2</keyword>
<url>http://www.bing.com</url>
<title>http://www.bing.com</title>
<date>2013-06-08 19:24:28</date>
<ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
</url>
<status>success</status>
<message>http://www.bing.com added to database</message>
<title>http://www.bing.com</title>
<shorturl>http://127.0.0.1/2</shorturl>
<statusCode>200</statusCode>
</result>
```

I only want the stuff in "shorturl"

However, I am getting an error in eclipse

```
    URL url=null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost/yourls/yourls-api.php?username=username&password=password&action=shorturl&url="+"http://google.ca");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
        String s = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = (Document) db.parse((url).openStream());

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = (XPathExpression) xpath.compile("shorturl");
        Object exprResult = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) exprResult;

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At

```
Object exprResult = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The error says "The method evaluate(Node, short, object) in the type XPathExpressions is not applicable for the arguments(Document, QName)"

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure the title, questions, and tags support and agree with the observed problems. Creating a "URL shortener" might be the overall task, but it has nothing to do with the problem. In this case, the problem is a *compile time error* due to invalid method usage - take a look at the XPathExpression.evaluate API - make sure you're looking at the *correct* API! - for valid signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have an import for a class named XPathExpression, but which is not the standard `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression`. This would also explain why you have a cast in your code:

```
XPathExpression expr = (XPathExpression) xpath.compile("shorturl");
```

it would not be required if the imported class was `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression`. The compiler probably wasn't happy with the simple assignment and the IDE proposed to "fix" it by adding a cast. But the problem is that you imported the wrong class.

Comment: I agree with this answer/synopsis. The method signature is valid for the standard XPathExpression type.

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is telling you everything you need: your `evaluate` method call has the wrong signature. Either pass the correct parameters (Node, short, Object), or overload the method with a signature you prefer (i.e. (Document, QName)). You'll have to either build the correct parameters from the ones you're currently using, or you'll have to write your own version of the `evaluate` method.